# Spring Boot 2.2.6 - MVC | How to ignore suffix and prefix defined in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, prefix, application.properties, suffix

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.6, I put these properties in application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=WEB-INF/pages/
```

But sometimes I need to ignore those properties. For example when I want to request "/deconnection"

```
@Controller
public class UserProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDelete deleteService;

    @RequestMapping({ "/userProfile" })
    public ModelAndView userProfile() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("members/userProfile");
        mv.addObject("page", "userProfile");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping({ "/deleteUser" })
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(Principal principal) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        deleteService.deleteUser(principal.getName());
        if (deleteService.getError() == null) {
            mv.setViewName("/deconnexion");
        } else {
            mv.setViewName("members/userProfile");
            mv.addObject("page", "userProfile");
            mv.addObject("error", deleteService.getError());
        }
        return mv;
    }
}
```

I don't want those properties to apply.
How to solve that ?

Thanks for your help !

:EDIT:

Use

```
mv.setViewName("redirect:/deconnexion");
```

to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use **redirect**, to go to desired url without prefixes.
Something like that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward#redirect-with-the-prefix-redirect

Comment: Thanks, I used `mv.setViewName("redirect:/deconnexion");` and it worked !